# Правильная работа с файлами

Tags: android

В моей программе я пытаюсь сделать следующее: если нет файла quest.txt, то создать его на карте памяти и записать туда число 1, если же он есть, то считать число из файла quest.txt некоторое число.
Вот фрагмент программы, отвечающей за это число:

```
         File fileName = null;
         String sdState = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
         if (sdState.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
             File sdDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
             fileName = new File(sdDir, "quest.txt");
         } 
         else {
             fileName = this.getCacheDir();
         }
         if (!fileName.exists()){
             fileName.mkdirs();
             try {
                 FileWriter f = new FileWriter(fileName);
                 f.write("1");
                 f.flush();
                 f.close();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
         else{
             try {
                 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
                 String str = "";
                 StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                 while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                     buffer.append(str);
                 }
                 br.close();
                 this.avi=str;
             } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
```

В ответ мне прилетает это:

```
05-25 20:31:12.522: W/System.err(10587): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/quest.txt: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
05-25 20:31:12.530: W/System.err(10587):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
05-25 20:31:12.530: W/System.err(10587):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:88)
05-25 20:31:12.530: W/System.err(10587):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:73)
05-25 20:31:12.530: W/System.err(10587):    at java.io.FileWriter.(FileWriter.java:42)
05-25 20:31:12.530: W/System.err(10587):    at com.example.thegameoflife.Quest.onCreate(Quest.java:90)
05-25 20:31:12.530: W/System.err(10587):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
05-25 20:31:12.530: W/System.err(10587):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
05-25 20:31:12.530: W/System.err(10587):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
05-25 20:31:12.530: W/System.err(10587):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
05-25 20:31:12.530: W/System.err(10587):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
05-25 20:31:12.530: W/System.err(10587):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
05-25 20:31:12.530: W/System.err(10587):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-25 20:31:12.530: W/System.err(10587):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
05-25 20:31:12.530: W/System.err(10587):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
05-25 20:31:12.537: W/System.err(10587):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 20:31:12.537: W/System.err(10587):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-25 20:31:12.537: W/System.err(10587):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
05-25 20:31:12.537: W/System.err(10587):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
05-25 20:31:12.537: W/System.err(10587):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-25 20:31:12.537: W/System.err(10587): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
05-25 20:31:12.537: W/System.err(10587):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
05-25 20:31:12.537: W/System.err(10587):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
05-25 20:31:12.537: W/System.err(10587):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
05-25 20:31:12.537: W/System.err(10587):    ... 18 more
```

Вот строка с ошибкой (90-я):

```
FileWriter f = new FileWriter(fileName);
```

Плюс ко всему в external storage появляется не файл, а папка с названием quest.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если почитать документацию, то можно увидеть, что

> mkdirs() Creates the directory named by this file, creating missing
>   parent directories if necessary.

Если почитать стактрейс, то можно увидеть, что

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/quest.txt: open
>   failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

Что означает, что запрашиваемый файл - это директория, которую вы предварительно создали, вызвав `fileName.mkdirs();`
Чтобы создать все папки в пути до файла, замените

```
fileName.mkdirs();
```

на

```
fileName.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

Не забудьте предварительно ручками удалить папку

> /storage/emulated/0/quest.txt

Да, это именно папка, а не файл.

И учтите ответ @Jenyay

Comment: Спасибо большое: эта ошибка прошла, но появилась другая. При повторном прогоне этого кода на устройстве программа заходит в последний else блок и жалуется на то, что str - null (я строчку avi парсером перегоняю в int, и парсер не находит там числа). Может я криво считываю строку? Я почему-то не смог найти в интернете способов адекватно считать строку из файла.

Comment: Во всяком случае в файле должна была бы быть строка "1" ...

Comment: И еще: я не могу найти на устройстве файл quest.txt. Это может быть как-то связано с тем, что начало имени пакета: com.example?

Comment: @IvanMotorin вы издеваетесь? вы **серьезно**  не смогли найти ,как прочитать из файла строку???

Comment: Это не очень важно. На задачу не сильно влияет, поскольку проверил: строку считываю правильно. Проблема где-то еще...

Answer (score 2):

getCacheDir() возвращает объект, который описывает абсолютный путь до **папки** с кэшем, и mkdirs() создает не файл, а папку.

Вам нужно сделать путь до файла. Например, так:

```
fileName = File (this.getCacheDir(), "quest.txt");
```