# Правильная работа с файлами №2

Tags: android

Перекат отсюда: [Правильная работа с файлами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426139/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/426196#426196)

В моей программе я пытаюсь сделать следующее: если нет файла quest.txt, то создать его на карте памяти и записать туда число 1, если же он есть, то считать число из файла quest.txt некоторое число. Вот фрагмент программы, отвечающей за это число:

```
         File fileName = null;
         String sdState = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
         if (sdState.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
             fileName = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "quest.txt");
         } 
         else {
             fileName = this.getCacheDir();
         }
         if (!fileName.exists()){
             fileName.getParentFile().mkdirs();
             try {
                 FileWriter f = new FileWriter(fileName);
                 f.write("1");
                 f.flush();
                 f.close();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
         else{
             try {
                 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
                 String str = "";
                 StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                 while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                     buffer.append(str);
                 }
                 br.close();
                 this.avi=str;
             } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         this.aviliable=Integer.parseInt(avi);
         }//код отличается от прошлого поста
```

При повторном заходе в этот кусок кода (файл уже создан) ловим:

```
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.thegameoflife/com.example.thegameoflife.Quest}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:355)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at com.example.thegameoflife.Quest.onCreate(Quest.java:115)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
05-29 20:58:41.816: E/AndroidRuntime(2109):     ... 11 more
```

Это происходит при попытке вытащить из строки avi целое число парсером.
Вот 115-я строка:

```
this.aviliable=Integer.parseInt(avi);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перевожу код на русский:

```
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer.append(str);
}
```

в str записать строку из файла. Пока в str что-то есть, делать следующее - добавить в буффер то, что сейчас в стр.
То есть, в итоге, после выполнения этого кода в str в любом случае окажется null.
Что вы делаете дальше:

```
this.avi=str;
this.aviliable=Integer.parseInt(avi);
```

Записываете то, что осталось в str в поле avi (напомню, в стр в любом случае остался null), и дальше пытаетесь спарсить то, что записалось в avi(напомню, записался туда null). И получаете вашу ошибку:

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"

А теперь как исправить ошибку:  заменить

```
this.avi=str;
```

на

`this.avi=buffer.toString();`